# Как сменить virtualenv в Anaconda 3?

Tags: python, virtualenv

[image: Вывод cmd]

Создаю новое окружение через `virtualenv myCMS`.
Каталоги создаются на диске.
Пытаюсь активировать через `activate` - активируется `[Anaconda3]`, а хотелось бы активировать `[myCMS]`.
Как правильно создавать и активировать **virtualenv** в данном случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждое виртуальное окружение имеет небольшой скрипт для активации, Anaconda вероятно прописала свой в PATH, поэтому команда `activate` в терминале просто активирует окружение `Anaconda3`. Чтобы это обойти, запустите скрипт активации, который конкретно относится к желаемому окружению, набрав:

```
D:\CODE\Python\Django\myCMS\Scripts\activate
```